# Angular 2 Cannot use directive form a nested module

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to define a directive that would hide elements if a user doesn't have a certain claim.

After i define the directive i declare it in application.module declarations.

The problem is that i am unable to use the directive from a module that is nested inside of application.module. If i use the directive inside a component that is 'next' to application module it works fine, but when i use the directive from a component that is inside of a nested module then it is not recognized by compiler and throws an error and if i declare the directive again compiler throws up again because it is being declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every module that uses a directive, needs to have the directive in `declarations` or have the module in `imports`, that has the directive in `declarations` and `exports`

Create a shared module

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [MyDirective],
  exports: [MyDirective],
}
export class SharedModule {}
```

and import it whereever you want to use directives or pipes from it:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [],
}
export class NestedModule {}
```

A directive can only be in `declarations` of exactly one module.
If you want to use a directive in various modules, you need to create a shared module.

Answer (score 5):

`Declarations` are not inherited by nested modules .You need to add your `Directive` into declarations for each `NgModule` where you want to use it. Also you can have a wrapper module for your directive like `YourDirectiveModule`, add your `Directive` into the `declarations` and then export them from `YourDirectiveModule`. Then import your `YourDirectiveModule` into each `NgModule` where you want to use it.

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [YourDirective],
   exports: [YourDirective]
})
export class YourDirectiveModule { }
```

And use

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [ YourDirectiveModule ]
})
export class SomeModule
```